# How can i delete a specific line

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to delete the line that corresponds the image, but when I use this code it deletes all the lines when clicking to any of the images ...

This is my code:

```js
const listPanierDelete = $("li > img");
const listPanier = $("#ListPanier");
const linePanier = listPanier.children('li');
const numberLinePanier = listPanier.children('li').length;
/*const listClassesArray = [];*/



for(let i = 0; i < numberLinePanier; i++){
    linePanier.addClass((i)=>{
        return "item-" + i
    })
    listPanierDelete.addClass((i)=>{
        return "item-" + i
    })


    listPanierDelete.on("click",()=>{
        listPanierDelete.closest("li").remove();
    });
```

And this is my HTML code (it's a screen from Devtool in Google Chrome because the original code in VSCode is an EJS template which is modified by my js code on loading, so I found this screen easier to understand the code in this context):

[image: screenshot of HTML code]

and here is the graphic result:

[image: screenshot of result]

How can I delete the line that corresponds to the image?

Comment: maybe `listPanierDelete.on("click", function() { this.closest("li").remove(); });`

Comment: @GrafiCode  It works better but this time it starts to delete the last line if i click any of images

Comment: The event handler applies to all `img` elements that are children of `li` elements. Using `this`, as @GrafiCode suggested, would work if you weren't adding the event handlers inside a loop. Move it above the loop.

Comment: Please, [edit] and create a [mcve]

Comment: Yes it worked ! my bad i put @GrafiCode function into the  for loops, so now its outside and this is the result i wanted to have .. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the second element that have the class name of item-0 or item-1 etc. I don't know why did you choose to give the image and the li the same class name, But this should work,
You just need to edit your code a little bit.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < numberLinePanier; i++)
{
   let _obj = document.getElementsByClassName(`item-${i}`);
   _obj[1].addEventListener("click", ( ) => {
      _obj[0].remove();
   });
}
```

It's supposed to work, i can't test it right now so good luck

Comment: it worked too ! i choose your answer because i don' t know why @GrafiCode function doesn't work anymore !